# Jenkins failed to obtain

Tags: java, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and was trying to figure out Nodes. After I made a new node and run from agent command line I got this. Could it be related to this supposed issue I got in the node status **"Java Web Start is not available for the JVM version running Jenkins"**?

```
INFO: Using C:\Data\Slave\remoting as a remoting work directory
эю с. 14, 2021 11:06:48 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager setupLogging
INFO: Both error and output logs will be printed to C:\Data\Slave\remoting
Failed to obtain http://8080/computer/DESKTOP/jenkins-agent.jnlp?encrypt=true
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:101)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:608)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:557)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1253)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.parseJnlpArguments(Launcher.java:509)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:347)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:298)
Waiting 10 seconds before retry'
```

Comment: is this line look correct to you?
Failed to obtain `http://8080/computer/DESKTOP/jenkins-agent.jnlp?encrypt=true`
Is that not missing a `localhost:` ?

Comment: The title of your question is "Jenkis failed to obtain". What did Jenkis fail to obtain? It looks like an important part of your title is missing.

Comment: @st.huber I had a hard time wording the question properly because I am unfamiliar with Jenkins. Basically, when I tried making a new node in Jenkins I got this issue above after downloading agent.jar and trying to run it from a command line. I have searched for answers everywhere but couldn't find anyone with a similiar issue.

Comment: @MinhKieu I am honestly not sure, is it supposed to have localhost in it?

Comment: your stacktrace looks to be opening an URL and the above URL looks broken. It should be something like http://<server-name-or-ipaddress>:<port>/<what-ever-path>